# How to do Boolean search in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean-logic

Can anyone suggest me some links or help me with some ideas about how to do the boolean search in ruby on rails.

I want to use boolean operators in search field like the below one:

```
(A OR B) AND (NOT C)

(A OR (C AND D)) AND (NOT (F OR G))
```

Reference:
[boolean-basics-job search](https://www.monster.com/career-advice/article/boolean-basics-job-search) -- this link explain the boolean search.

But how to implement this search with ruby on rails?

Is there any way to do it in ruby on rails?

Hope this clarifies.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure you want to use SQL logic or Ruby logic. So
Ruby logic

```
1. (A || B) && !C
2. (A || (C && D)) && !(F || G)
```

Rails ActiveRecord search (SQL)

1. `Model.where('a = ? OR b = ?', a_value, b_value).where.not('c = ?', c_value)`
2. `Model.where('a = ? OR (c = ? AND d = ?)', a_value, c_value, d_value).where.not('f = ? OR g = ?', f_value, g_value)`

Of course it would me much better if you create scopes for that methods.

```
class Model
  scope :first_scope, ->(a_value, b_value) { where('a = ? OR b = ?', a_value, b_value) }
  scope :second_scope, -> (c_value) { where.not('c = ?', c_value) }
end
```

And then

```
Model.first_scope(a_value, b_value).second_scope(c_value)
```

Comment: can u tell me SQL logic too

Comment: Its in ActiveRecord logic. ActiveRecord is 'mapping' it to SQL but here: `"SELECT 'some_table'.* FROM 'some_table' WHERE  a = 't' OR (b = 't' AND c = 'f')) AND ( d != 't')"` If you want to see SQL generated by AR you can use: `Model.first_scope(a_value, b_value).second_scope(c_value).to_sql`

Answer (score 0):

Logical OR = ||
Logical AND = &&
Logical NOT = ! or not()

```
(A || B) && !C

(A || (C && D)) && !(F || G)
```